# How to load my own data (which is not image based) instead of mnist data

Tags: python, image-processing, multidimensional-array, dataset, mnist

MNIST expects a specific format, so it would need to store the data in the same format and name accordingly.

What if I want to upload my multidimensional data (1335x12 and .csv format), which is not an image data; instead of MNSIT data?
How to approach with that?

The sample rows from my data:
[image]

I am working on anaconda with pytorch!

Comment: Can you provide sample rows from your csv?

Comment: @SultanOrazbayev I have updated the question with sample rows from my data!